# SQL count all of the column that has a value greater than 10 and sum it up

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to count all of the column in my table that has value >= 10.
here is my table :

> > Date   #####   ||     Value1 ||  Value2 ||   Value3
> >
> > 23/04/2014 || __ 1,2  || __  12,3 ||__   10  ||
> >
> > 23/04/2014  ||__ 11,2  || ____   3  || __    10,3  ||
> >
> > 24/04/2014 || __ 10,9  || ____   3  || __    1  ||

I want it to display:

> > Date   #####   ||     Count ||
> >
> > 23/04/2014 || __ 4 ||
> >
> > 24/04/2014 || __ 1  ||

Assume that I have a lot of date, I want it to display only the last 3 rows.

here is my first code :

```
Dim strCommand As String = "Select Date, count(*) as tcount from tbBooth having count(*) >= 10 group by date"
```

already changed based on the solution from Collapsar into this:

```
Dim strCommand As String = "Select t.d, sum(t.valcount) cnt from (select [date] AS d, CASE WHEN t1.ManualAssists1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN t1.ManualAssists2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN t1.ManualAssists3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS valcount from tbBooth t1) t group by t.d"
```

it's works, but I want to display only the last 3 row based on ASC order.
Is there anyway how to do it?

Thanks in advances....

Comment: Not the answer, but explain the Syntax Error. Date is a reserved keyword. You need square brackets around it `[Date]`

Comment: The syntax error is caused by the HAVING clause. The HAVING clause must appear AFTER the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
select t.d
     , sum(t.valcount) cnt
  from (
         select [date] AS d
              ,   CASE WHEN t1.value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                + CASE WHEN t1.value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                + CASE WHEN t1.value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                       AS valcount
           from table t1
       ) t
group by t.d
     ;
```

Comment: Dear Collapsar,
I want to ask again, do you know how to display only the last two row in ASC order...
Thanks...

Comment: @user3567963 Unfortunately I don't know the answer for sql server offhand. I can look into it tomorrow. In any case I suggest that you make it another SO question, as it might be of general interest.

Comment: Thank you for replying my comment. The problem has been solved on my other post. Thank you for your suggestion Sir.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   D,
   SUM(one + two + three) AS tcount
FROM 
   (
      SELECT
        [Date] AS D,
        CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS one,
        CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS two, 
        CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS three
      FROM
        tbBooth 
   )
GROUP BY 
   D
```